# Find and replace words in a text file (Java GUI)

Tags: java

I'm looking to create a find and replace java application which prompts users to call to a text file, print it out to a new file, ask user for a search word or phrase and a word to replace that searched word with. Here is the code I have so far. I can read the contents from the first file just fine but cannot write the contents from the first file to another. This is all done within a GUI code below

```
    String loc = jTextField1.getText(); //gets location of initial file or "source"
    String file = jTextField4.getText(); //new file path
    String find = jTextField2.getText(); //find word inputted by user
    String word = jTextField3.getText(); //replace "find" with word inputted by user
    String line = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(loc));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null)


    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Assign6GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Assign6GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To write content to a file you need to use BufferedWriter

```
public static void writetoFile(String str, String FILE_PATH, String FILENAME ) { 
  BufferedWriter writer = null; 
  try { 
    File file = new File(FILE_PATH); 
    // if file doesnt exists, then create it  
    if (!file.exists()) { 
      file.mkdir(); 
    } 
    file = new File(FILE_PATH + FILENAME); 
    file.createNewFile(); 

    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)); 
    writer.write(str); 
  } catch (IOException e) { 
    LOGGER.debug(e); 
  } finally { 
    try { 
      if (writer != null) { 
        writer.close(); 
      } 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
      LOGGER.debug(e); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

to replace words in a string you should use the replace function in java

```
String str = someString.replace("OldText", "NewText");
```